# Why does my h2 and div have the same font-size

Tags: html, css, font-size

I'm attempting to convert an element. The font-size conversion works fine, but the margin conversion isn't doing so great.

Here is my attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">    
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .box{
        font-size:30px;
        margin:23px 0;
        font-weight:bold;

    }
    </style>
    </head>

<body>

</head>
<body>

<div class="box">Some text here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Compared to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">    
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-size:20px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

<body>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Some text here</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the H2 and the .box text have the same font-size when viewed in a browser.

This is incorrect, and should be 24px. What mistake have I made?

Comment: Why should it be 24px? Your calculation is correct and .75em equals 22.5px You could just use .77em (23/30) to be sure the browser will not round down.

Comment: When viewed in a browser, the text in the H2 and the .box aren't exactly aligned - they're off by 1px, which sounds like not a big deal but i need it to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You set the font size for the body which other elements will inherit but h2 is preset by the browser internally by the user agent css, specifically, as in 'specificity' and takes precedence over what you set for the body.

If you use Firebug, for example, you will see the browser has already set h2 to some value in your browser. If you want to change that, you need to specify `h2{font-size: 24px}` as you did in your other example with the div. Divs do not have a font-size set on them by the browser.

Answer (score -1):

The `margin` property for a `div` element is preset by default in all browsers, whereas the `font-size` property is not. To override it, you need to be more specific, by using this:

```
div.box { font-size:30px; margin:23px 0; font-weight:bold; }
```